# Sending arduino sensor data via WiFi to a MySQL server

Tags: wifi, mkr1010

I'm aware this question has probably been asked many times but I'm pulling my hair out.

I'm trying to get sensor data from an arduino to a MySQL server. I've checked the apache access log and the request is there. But it just isn't being inserted into the database. Manually adding the data using the browser works so the php code seems fine. I've allowed apache through the firewall and updated the permissions all to no avail. Code below:

Arduino Main Code:

```
#include "thingProperties.h"
#include <Arduino_MKRENV.h>
#include <WiFi.h>


WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
  delay(1500);
  
  //Connect to WiFi network
  int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(SSID);
    status = WiFi.begin(SSID, PASS);
    delay(10000);
  }
  Serial.println("This is connected.");

  if (!ENV.begin()) {
  Serial.println("Failed to initialize MKR ENV shield!");
  while(1);
  }
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
 relativeHumidity = int(ENV.readHumidity());
 lightIntensity = (ENV.readIlluminance());
 airPressure = int(ENV.readPressure(MILLIBAR));
 temperature = int(ENV.readTemperature());
 if(digitalRead(2) == LOW){
   rain = 1;
 }else if(digitalRead(2) == HIGH){
   rain = 0;
 }
 Serial.println("httpRequest");
 httpRequest();
 delay(10000);
}

void httpRequest(){
  // if there's a successful connection:
  if (client.connect(SERVER, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to server...");
    // send the HTTP PUT request:
    client.print("GET /weather_data.php?temp=");
    Serial.println("GET /weather_data.php?);
    client.print(temperature);
    client.print("&pressure=");
    client.print(airPressure);
    client.print("&humidity=");
    client.print(relativeHumidity);
    client.print("&illumination=");
    client.print(lightIntensity);
    client.print("&rain=");
    client.print(rain);
    client.print(" ");
    client.println("HTTP/1.1");
    client.print(" Host: ");
    client.println(SERVER);
    client.println();
    Serial.println("Added.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Not connected.");
  }
  if (client.connected()){
    client.stop();
  }
}
```

thingProperties.h:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
 
const char THING_ID[] = "c942a18f-7696-4431-952c-76eaea3214ea";

const char SSID[]     = SECRET_SSID;    // Network SSID (name)
const char PASS[]     = SECRET_PASS;    // Network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
const char SERVER[]   = SECRET_IP;      // Server IP Address

int airPressure;
float lightIntensity;
float relativeHumidity;
bool rain;
float temperature;
```

Comment: So your Arduino is using a WiFi library to submit HTTP commands to a server running an Apache web server stack? And you are seeing the commands logged to the server? If so, you're going to have to debug the sever side of this. Is the command well formed when received? What is being done with it? You say "Manually adding the data using the browser works so the php code seems fine." That is too much of a leap. Using a web client to submit your request vs. doing it from a raw HTTP GET command exercises a different path on your server.

Comment: does the record get inserted when you use a web browser? ... if it does, copy the URL and include as a comment in your code

Comment: The following is an example of the requests directly from the access log: 192.168.0.3 - - [24/Jun/2020:21:26:58 +0100] "GET /weather_data.php?temp=32.00&pressure=1009&humidity=40.00&illumination=3.23&rain=0 HTTP/1.1" 400 311

Comment: the 400 is HTTP response code? see the WebClient example on how to print the HTTP response in Arduino

Answer (score 2):

So I don't quite know why, but I started from scratch and it works now. I've put the new code below in case it helps someone in my situation.

```
// Arduino Low Power - Version: Latest 
//#include <ArduinoLowPower.h>
//#include <ArduinoIoTCloud.h>
#include "thingProperties.h"
#include <Arduino_MKRENV.h>
/*
  Repeating Wifi Web Client

  This sketch connects to a a web server and makes a request
  using a WiFi equipped Arduino board.

  created 23 April 2012
  modified 31 May 2012
  by Tom Igoe
  modified 13 Jan 2014
  by Federico Vanzati

  http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WifiWebClientRepeating
  This code is in the public domain.
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

// Initialize the Wifi client library
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the WiFi module:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv < WIFI_FIRMWARE_LATEST_VERSION) {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    //Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    //Serial.println(SSID);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(SSID, PASS);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  // you're connected now, so print out the status:
  //printWifiStatus();
  //Start arduino cloud.
  //ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);
  //Begin ENV shield.
  if (!ENV.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize MKR ENV shield!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  //ArduinoCloud.update();
  // if there's incoming data from the net connection.
  // send it out the serial port.  This is for debugging
  // purposes only:
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }
    //Serial.println("Start reading sensors.");
    relativeHumidity = int(ENV.readHumidity());
    //Serial.println(relativeHumidity);
    lightIntensity = int(ENV.readIlluminance());
    //Serial.println(lightIntensity);
    airPressure = int(ENV.readPressure(MILLIBAR));
    //Serial.println(airPressure);
    temperature = int(ENV.readTemperature());
    //Serial.println(temperature);
    UV_Index = int(ENV.readUVIndex());
    //Serial.println(UV_Index);
    if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {
      rain = 1;
    } else if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
      rain = 0;
    }
    //Serial.println(rain);
    //Serial.println("Sensor data read.");
    //Serial.println("Start http request.");
    httpRequest();
    //Serial.println("Stop http request");
    delay(60000);
}

// this method makes a HTTP connection to the server:
void httpRequest() {
  // close any connection before send a new request.
  // This will free the socket on the Nina module
  client.stop();

  // if there's a successful connection:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    //Serial.println("connecting...");
    // send the HTTP PUT request:
    client.print("GET /weather_data.php?temp=");
    client.print(temperature);
    client.print("&pressure=");
    client.print(airPressure);
    client.print("&humidity=");
    client.print(relativeHumidity);
    client.print("&illumination=");
    client.print(lightIntensity);
    client.print("&UV_Index=");
    client.print(UV_Index);
    client.print("&rain=");
    client.print(rain);
    client.print(" ");
    client.println("HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.0.29");
    client.println("User-Agent: ArduinoWiFi/1.1");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you couldn't make a connection:
    //Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

Comment: I see you don't use the WiFi library but the WiFiNINA library

Answer (score 0):

WiFi.h is for Arduino WiFi shield. Use the WiFiNINA library for MKR1010

Comment: Made that change but still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @SamAnderson, maybe it doesn't work yet, but with WiFiNINA it has at least a chance to work.